# Serializing objects with changing class source code

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream

> **Note:** *Due to the lack of questions like this on SO, I've decided to put one up myself as a Q&A*

Serializing objects (using an `ObjectOutputStream` and an `ObjectInputStream`) is a method for storing an instance of a `Java Object` as data that can be later deserialized for use. This can cause problems and frustration when the `Class` used to deserialize the data does not remain the same (source-code changes; program updates).

So how can an `Object` be serialized and deserialized with an updated / downgraded version of a `Class`?

Comment: You need to read the [Versioning of Serializable Objects chapter of the Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html).

Comment: Although saving objects as `JSON`, `XML`, and so fourth is a common practice in all languages, this post is specifically geared towards Java and its available classes. The title should include Java.

Comment: Please do not add tags in the question title: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/182862).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few common ways of serializing an object that can be deserialized in a backwards-compatible way.

**1.** Store the data in the [**JSON**](http://www.json.org/) format using `import` and `export` methods designed to save all fields needed to recreate the instance. This can be made backwards-compatible by including a `version` key that allows for an update algorithm to be called if the version is too low. A common library for this is the [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library which can represent Java objects in JSON as well as normally editing a JSON file.

**2.** Use the built-in java [**Properties**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class in a way similar to the method described above. Properties objects can be later stored using a stream (`store()`) written as a regular Java Properties file, or saved in [**XML**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) (`storeToXML()`).

**3.** Sometimes simple objects can be easily represented with key-value pairs in a place where storing them in a JSON, XML, or Properties file is either too complicated or not neccessary (*overkill* one could say). In this case, an effective way of serializing the object could be using the [**ObjectOutputStream**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) class to serialize a `HashMap` object containing key-value pairs where the key could be a `String` and the value could be an `Object` (`HashMap<String,Object>`). This allows for all of the object's fields to be stored as well as including a `version` key while providing much versatility.

**Note:** Although serializing an object using the `ObjectOutputStream` for persistence storage is normally considered bad convention, it can be used either way as long as the class' source code remains the same.

**Also Note about versioning:** Changes to a class can be safely made without disrupting deserialization using an `ObjectOutputStream` as long as they are a **compatible change**. As mentioned in the [*Versioning of Serializable Objects chapter of the Object Serialization Specification*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html):

> A compatible change is a change that does not affect the contract
>   between the class and its callers.

Comment: Why there's no approach showing usage of `readObject` and `writeObject` methods?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Using `readObject` and `writeObject` is what is implied by mentioning the `ObjectOutputStream` class. I've added a link to it's Javadocs for easy finding.

Comment: Final sentence is incorrect. `ObjectOutputStream` can be used *as long as the [constraints mentioned in the Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) are observed.*